# Select Statement to select records from two tables based on ID entered in Textbox

Tags: asp.net, mysql, subquery

I have two SQL Tables, an Attendance Table which has the fields AttendanceID, StudentID, ModuleID, Present and Date. The other table is Student Table, which has StudentID field and Name field. 
I want to generate an SQL statement which selects the AttendanceID, StudentID, ModuleID, Present and Date from the Attendance Table but also selects the Name field in the Student Table depending on the StudentID entered in a Textbox Control.
Could anyone help me with the SQL to achieve this, I think I need a subQuery but I do not know how to do this as I am only a beginner with MySQL.
Here is my code so far which selects all the fields in the Attendance Table but does not select the Name from the Student Table based on the StudentID chosen.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RegisterConnectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Attendance] WHERE ([StudentID] = @StudentID)">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="pnumTextBox" Name="StudentID" 
                            PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to join `Student` and `Attendance` tables to get that information. Here is a query which would do that.

```
SELECT AttendanceID, Student.StudentID, ModuleID, Present, Date, Name 
FROM Attendance, Student 
WHERE Attendance.StudentID = Student.StudentID 
AND (Student.StudentID = @StudentID)
```

Comment: StudentID is ambiguous because it exists in both tables.  Change the select statement @Ravi provided to prefix all the selected columns with the correct TableName.  I.e. SELECT Student.AttendanceID, Student.StudentID, ...etc.  Alternatively, use [table aliases](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/SQLServer/0020__Query/Tablealias.htm) for readability